# Loop over the dataframe with iloc function

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I am new to python. I am hoping to use a loop to insert the result into each cell of the columns using iloc, but I don't know why the columns only have nan returned except the "100000" output. Please advise if possible. Thank you very much.

```
for i in range(data.shape[0]):

    data['Money'] = np.nan

    data['Money'].iloc[0] = 100000

    data['Numbers of things'] = np.nan
    data['Numbers of things'].iloc[i] = data['Money'].iloc[i] / (data['perspectives'].iloc[i] * 100)
```

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for you can accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop. You can create columns as a whole:

```
data['Money'] = np.nan
data['Money'].iloc[0] = 100000
data['Numbers of things'] = data['Money'] / (data['perspectives'] * 100)
```

Be aware that all rows of column 'Money' but the first one are NaN by construction.

**Edit:**
If you want to populate a column with values from the previous rows of other columns you can use the method `.shift(1)` to *shift* the column by one row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2, 2,3]})
df['c']=df['a'].shift(1) - df['b'].shift(1)
df

    a   b   c
0   1   2   NaN
1   2   2   -1.0
2   3   3   0.0
```

Comment: As I need to do something more like this: 

data['Monthly P&L'].iloc[i+1] = data['Numbers of put shorted'].iloc[i] * (data['Realized Loss due to exercising'].iloc[i])

I need to use the next row result to create the results of other columns' cells in the next row. I want to loop over using the iloc function. Could you suggest a way for me to do so?

Comment: This is different from your original question. I will edit my answer.